# How do I fade colour in some areas of a photo with Photoshop?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, color

[image: sample photo]

I have photos of biological tissue samples (the attached photo is not mine, it is just an example), which were stained with dye. Because of the nature of the tissue, the staining is uneven (some areas have higher color and some areas are fainter). I would like to fade the area where the color is too high with Photoshop. I am not familiar with the tool. Can anyone please advise me how I can adjust the color of the photos so that the whole photo looks more evenly colored?

Comment: Please post an example image!

Comment: hi, @null, I have attached an example photo, where some area are yellow and most are orange. How can I even and smooth the photo. Tks.

Comment: Do you want to do this while retaining accurate information in the bright areas? Because I think they are too 'blown out' for that. If you want them to just _look_ more even without being 'accurate', you can simply clone/patch them out.

Answer (score 1):

It is handy to do the following:

- open in program
- create new layer
- set the blending mode of new layer to "saturation"
- paint the new layer with black or white (or any other colour with zero saturation) with varying brush opacity to make colour look pale
- use eraser to cancel effect completely or partially
- use layer opacity to control the overall effect

Answer (score 1):

Open the image in to Photoshop
Create adjustment layer for hue and saturation
Fade/increase the saturation
Paint with black on the layer mask to hide/reveal the color
Create another adjustment layer if you required more modifications